# regex - Edit Bash arrays in text file

Tags: regex, sed, gnu

I would like to change the following piece:

```
# Source
source=('10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf'
        '20-nvidia.conf'
        'linux-4.11.patch')
source_i686=("http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/$pkgver/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-$pkgver.run")
source_x86_64=("http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/$pkgver/$_pkg.run")
md5sums=('4f5562ee8f3171769e4638b35396c55d'
         '2640eac092c220073f0668a7aaff61f7'
         '897d9775dc484ab37934e7b102c5b325')
md5sums_i686=('8825cec1640739521689bd80121d1425')
md5sums_x86_64=('0e9590d48703c8baa034b6f0f8bbf1e5')
[[ $_pkg = NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-$pkgver ]] && md5sums_x86_64=('1b74150e84fd99cc1207a51b9327112c')
```

into:

```
# Source
source=('10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf'
        '20-nvidia.conf')
#        'linux-4.11.patch')
source_i686=("http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/$pkgver/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-$pkgver.run")
source_x86_64=("http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/$pkgver/$_pkg.run")
md5sums=('4f5562ee8f3171769e4638b35396c55d'
         '2640eac092c220073f0668a7aaff61f7')
#         '897d9775dc484ab37934e7b102c5b325')
md5sums_i686=('8825cec1640739521689bd80121d1425')
md5sums_x86_64=('0e9590d48703c8baa034b6f0f8bbf1e5')
[[ $_pkg = NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-$pkgver ]] && md5sums_x86_64=('1b74150e84fd99cc1207a51b9327112c')
```

..to comment out the last item in `source` and `md5sums` and close the arrays (`)`).

I only know how to do 1/4th and comment out the `'linux-4.11.patch')` with:

```
sed "/'linux-.*patch'/s/^/#/"
```

Sed version:

```
$ sed --version | head -1
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
```

Comment: do they always have 3 entries? can there be `(` and `)` characters inside the array elements? what is your sed version, does it have -z option?

Comment: @Sundeep `"do they always have 3 entries?"` if it makes it a lot easier, I can go with that. `"can there be ( and ) characters inside the array elements?"` that's not Bash? `"what is your sed version, does it have -z option?"` GNU sed 4.4, yes.

Comment: I mean array entries like `20-nvidia.conf` can it be something like `(20)-nvidia.conf` also?

Comment: @Sundeep oh. No. There's no bracket characters in the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no `()` characters inside the array elements and no NUL characters in file

```
$ sed -zE 's/((source|md5sums)=\([^)]*)\n([^)\n]*\))/\1)\n#\3/g' input_file 
# Source
source=('10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf'
        '20-nvidia.conf')
#        'linux-4.11.patch')
source_i686=("http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/$pkgver/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-$pkgver.run")
source_x86_64=("http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/$pkgver/$_pkg.run")
md5sums=('4f5562ee8f3171769e4638b35396c55d'
         '2640eac092c220073f0668a7aaff61f7')
#         '897d9775dc484ab37934e7b102c5b325')
md5sums_i686=('8825cec1640739521689bd80121d1425')
md5sums_x86_64=('0e9590d48703c8baa034b6f0f8bbf1e5')
[[ $_pkg = NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-$pkgver ]] && md5sums_x86_64=('1b74150e84fd99cc1207a51b9327112c')
```

- `-z` will cause whole file to be read at once
- `-E` extended regular expression
- `((source|md5sums)=\([^)]*)\n([^)\n]*\))` will cause `source=(...)` or `md5sums=(...)` match in two halves, with second half containing last line
- `\1)\n#\3` replace as per requirement

If number of lines is known to be fixed number,

```
sed '/^source=\|^md5sums=/ {N;N; s/\n/)\n#/2}' input_file
```

where `N;N` and `2` will be number of lines minus one

Comment: Works nicely :-).